# Linking Content Types to Pages

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, navigation

I have multiple content types like news, publications, etc and I will like to link them to pages on my site. So when a user posts a news item on a specific page, it only shows up on that page only. Also I will want users to be able to edit content on only pages they have been assigned to. Eg. A user will only be allowed to add news to pages they have rights to.
I was considering using groups for this, but I know more suggestions will be helpful.

Many thanks
Isacc

Answer (score 0):

You can create different views and filter the content types.

Comment: Thanks John, but how do I restrict editing of the content types to only pages users have rights to?

Comment: you can use node_access module to restrict the content types/content